# Matlab checking if user input is a point on my plot

Tags: matlab, if-statement, plot, graph, conditional-statements

I've been trying to figure out how to do this now for a couple of hours. I have two equations that become plotted in an (x,y) format

```
x = v*cosd(theta)*t;
y = -(g*t.^2)/2 + v*sind(theta)*t;
plot(x,y)
```

Variables v, theta, xanimal, yanimal are filled by user input once the program is ran. xanimal and yanimal are basically where the single point will be while v and theta are variables that go into to equations above that creates the trajectory. 
What I'm looking for is some conditional statement that determines if the point (xanimal, yanimal) is on the plot or within 0.5 of the plot (x,y). 
The plot (x,y) is ever changing since the values for the equation is filled via user input.

I've tried different things which none have worked.

```
 One Attempt

 for i=1:max(x)
 if xanimal == x(i) && yanimal == y
 disp('Success')
 end
 end
```

This method also did not work

```
Second Attempt
Xmax_animal = xanimal +.5;
Xmin_animal = x-.5;

Ymax_animal = y+.5
Ymin_animal = y-.5
Y_animal = linspace(max(y),min(y),1)

if(Y_animal>max1)
disp('food fight')
else

a = find(y >= Y_animal);
b = x(a);
d = b(1);
c1 = b(end); 

if (Xmax_animal >= d) && (d >= Xmin_animal)
set(handles.edit5, 'String', 'Success')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "within 0.5 of the plot (x,y)" mean that the euclidian distance (over the y-axis) between your point and the line should not exceed 0.5, right ?

Comment: As an idea to try, on the Matlab Exchange, this function is available https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34869-distance2curve
Could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distance function that uses both coordinates instead of each coordinate separately. The following should work:

```
function d = dist(x , y, xpoint, ypoint)
    d = sqrt( (x - xpoint).^2 + (y - ypoint).^2 );
end
```

You can call this point giving it your x and y vectors and your xanimal and yanimal points to produce an array of distances. Then use

```
if sum(d < 0.5) > 0 
    disp('Close enough!');
else 
    disp('too far away');
end
```

Comment: So are xpoint and ypoint just place holders where I would enter xanimal and yanimal?

Comment: yes, exactly, you can call the function with `d = dist(x, y, xanimal, yanimal)` or whatever variables you want and it will create the variable `d` with the result of the function.